# What should be used for WCF service monitoring ? WMI or WS-Discovery

Tags: wcf, wmi, ws-discovery

Can you tell that which is the best tool to monitor WCF services, WMI or WS-Discovery implementation.

Comment: Hi, what kind of monitoring? timings, errors, is running, ..?

Comment: specifically status of the service whether available or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements look easy, but in fact it's quite difficult. Service may be available but operations may fails and vice-versa. There are also many potential problems : network failure, pool/service host stopped, wcf activation fails, operation errors... A service can be available but all operations fails because of a corrupt database. WMI/Perf counters seems to be a good approach as you can have many details for different scopes (service/operation/endpoint). But In addition if your hosting your service under IIS, application pool idle default timeout is 20 minutes: counters/WMI will be unavailable.

In conclusion, i would said that the best monitoring strategy is an agregation of all tools/components available to server side and to client side.

Comment: any limitations of WS-Discovery if it is used for discovery and service status?

Comment: WCF services hosted under IIS or WAS do not run until IIS/WAS receives a message bound for the service, so they cannot be discoverable by default. You have to use AppFabric Auto-Start feature. As i said, your service can be up, but all your operations may fails. In py opinion, it is not enough for monitoring.