# Monitoring WCF with nagios

Tags: wcf, monitoring, nagios

I'm not familiar with Nagios and I'm still half way looking through the plugins and documentation but our client is currently using this and they want to use it to monitor our WCF too. Is there a way for Nagios to consume WCF methods or at least monitor the errors thrown by the WCF?

Answer (score 2):

In our company, we are using Nagios for monitoring. We have also many WCF services. The only method we found is deploying NsClient++ on each server and collect WCF performance counters (calls/completed/faults, durations) There are many counters for us.

As i previously said, monitoring WCF is quite painful. see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297076/what-should-be-used-for-wcf-service-monitoring-wmi-or-ws-discovery/12313529#12313529)

Comment: Any links or simple directions for me to get started on NsClient++ and connect/monitor the WCF?

Comment: You will get the list of performance counters here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx. Monitoring performance counters may be included in your version of nagios. I can not help you for NsClient++ because it was not my job and i don't want to simply copy/paster results from google. There are many tutorials available on internet. For my team, it was not too difficult. The real challenge with Nagios is that it's a "linux" solution.

Comment: @Cybermaxs once you configured the perfmon to monitor WCF services what's the best way to grab info and log them